# Flask redirect client based on localhost or network request

Tags: python, flask, routes, flask-socketio

I want to allow the localhost user to be able to access all flask pages, but want to block 'outsiders' to only one specific page. I am looking for a way to do this. Any ideas how?

so if the user is on the  device itself i want to access routes: all
if the user is from a different device he has to be redirected to: extern-client page

Is this possible? if so, how?

Comment: The safest way to do this is to host two separate web application, one for internal users listening on localhost, and one for external listening on 0.0.0.0. You can do it with a single app by checking client IP address and filter access to routes with a custom decorator, but this is way more complicated and you always risk making a mistake and giving access to someone you shouldn't.

Comment: Thnx, but as I also need the external page for the internal application, what would be the best way to achieve this? I am only using the flask as the GUI for my “bigger” application. The back-end would have to be shared by the two flask apps.

Comment: As I said above, you can write a custom decorator (or maybe a before_request handler) that denies access to users that don't have a certain approved IP address. Start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251038/how-to-limit-flask-dev-server-to-only-one-visiting-ip-address

Comment: What's a "localhost user"?

Comment: The client that visits the webpage from the same device. Sorry for confusion . The issue here is to differentiate between a client/user on the same device or from another device on the network. (In my context)