# Limit Heroku Website To Certain IP Addresses

Tags: python, flask, heroku, ip

Using Python and Flask is there any way to limit my web app to certain IP addresses?

To be more specific, I would like to access my Heroku app via the internet from only specific devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251038/how-to-limit-flask-dev-server-to-only-one-visiting-ip-address) with Flask though I agree with the other comments on that post that this should really be done at the networking level. That cannot really be done on Heroku unless you use Private Spaces which has the [Trusted IPs feature](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces#trusted-ip-ranges).